# Invoking the web api get method with multiple parameters returns 404 not found error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have written the following HttpGet method and calling it with 2 parameters. When I try invoking it via postman , I get 404 
not found error. Not sure what the problem is in my call

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("unique-email/{clientCompanyId:int}/{email}")]
    public IActionResult UniqueEmail( int clientCompanyId, string email )
    {
        _identityService.CheckUniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email );

        return Ok();
    }
```

I tried the following ways to invoke it

```
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email=test@test.co.uk
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email="test@test.co.uk"
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email='test@test.co.uk'
```

Code

```
 public bool CheckUniqueEmail(int clientCompanyId, string email)
    {
        return _userUow.UniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email);
    }

    public bool UniqueEmail(int clientCompanyId, string email)
    {
        bool anyMatching = ClientCompanyContactRepository.Get()
             .Any(x => x.Email == email && x.ClientCompanyId == clientCompanyId);
        return !anyMatching;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:57973/unique-email/29/test@test.co.uk`?

Comment: Yes tried. Same error

Comment: Same error again

Comment: Do you have any Route attribute on controller? Any route prefix like api? I've just checked your code on my PC and it works fine with `/unique-email/29/test@test.co.uk`

Comment: I now understood what the problem is . I was missing api and controller name . It should be http://localhost:57973/api/security/unique-email/29/test@test.co.uk

Comment: Sure thank you. would pass in route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if you have a `Route` attribute on controller or set any url prefix like `api` somewhere.

Your urls doesn't meets the requirement path

```
/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email=test@test.co.uk
```

because route attribute is

```
[Route("unique-email/{clientCompanyId:int}/{email}")]
```

it means that url should be

```
/unique-email/29/test@test.co.uk
```

If you need to pass parameters as a query string then use `[FromQuery]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

The route you use in the controller is incorrect with the route you specify in the postman.

your Route

```
[Route("unique-email/{clientCompanyId:int}/{email}")]
```

And Uses

```
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email=test@test.co.uk
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email="test@test.co.uk"
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email='test@test.co.uk'
```

With this route you used in the code you can use it in the postman

```
http://localhost:57973/unique-email/29/test@test.co.uk
```

But if you want to route your route as you did in the postman you first built, make a change to your code.

```
 [HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("unique-email")]
public IActionResult UniqueEmail([FromQuery] int clientCompanyId, [FromQuery] string email )
{
    _identityService.CheckUniqueEmail(clientCompanyId, email );

    return Ok();
}
```

And Postman

```
http://localhost:57973/unique-email?clientCompanyId=29&email="test@test.co.uk"
```